# How to Change OnHover Background Color of DataGrid Row?

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I have a Silverlight DataGrid and I can't figure out how to style it.  When the user hovers over a row, the background color that is applied to the row (by default) does not fit well with the rest of the UI.  I want to change this background color on hover.  How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a `DataGridRow` Style to `DataGrid.RowStyle` that changes the animation for the VisualState for MouseOver.  The Default styles for DataGrid can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278066%28VS.95%29.aspx).

In the style for DataGridRow you want to change this:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundRectangle" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Opacity="0" Fill="#FFBADDE9"/>
```

That Rectangle is opaque but is made visible on mouse over.  Changing the fill will change the background color on mouse over.

Comment: Thank you!  I was looking for that default style XAML.  Sometimes MSDN docs really aggravate me; things are too hard to find there!

Comment: Stephan, I have one more problem that I think is related.  For whatever reason, the cell/column that was clicked on gets a lighter background color than the other cells in the row.  How can I change this?  I'd like the entire row to always be the same background color.  It appears that the opacity is turned up a little on the cell that was clicked on, resulting in a slightly brighter color.

Comment: You need to do the exact same thing only with the cell style.  The default cell style (same link) has a element, name 'FocusVisual', that is set to non opaque when the cell is selected.  Remove that element and the animation and it will stop it from changing the look.

Comment: Thanks!  Seems silly to have to inject this huge portion of XAML just to tweak something like this, but hey, whatever works.

Comment: @Josh I completely agree about the ridiculous volume of XAML.  In the project I'm currently on I had to completely restyle a DataGrid and the styles alone are 400+ lines of XAML.